# Install two versions of the same app

Tags: installation, music, google-play-music

I am trying to install the old (holo) version of Google Play Music on my device ( http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1477066&d=1352756915 - VERSION    Google_Play_Music_v4.4.811H.526848.apk to be exact ) because I only use local media files and the new orange cremesickle version from the past year or so is terrible at this and I loathe it.

However, my roomates have an All Access Subscription which requires the new version, leading to a lot of tension over what version to keep on the device.

I have read that it is possible to install two versions of an app side by side by changing the package name via APKtool. This seems like a trivial thing to do, but it is not working for me.

Following the guide at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2760965 i attempted to change the package name, but the line 'cur_package_name' and 'orig_package_name' are not in my apktool.yml, and there is an additional 'original-package' entry in the androidmanifest alogside the line with the package attribute.

Also, upon doing the find-replace trick with notepad++ that they mentioned, it is unable to find any occurrences.

Where can I go from here? I attempted to recompile and run the app on the tablet, but it force closes immediately as something is incomplete. Is there a version of this app that is already modded for side by side loading out there? or how can I proceed?

Comment: Or see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218641/renaming-the-package-name-inside-an-apk